# How to find average and power of a signal

Tags: discrete-signals, homework

I need to find the average and the power of this signal:

$$x(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-k}e^{j2{\pi}kn}$$

The problem is that the summation starts at 1 and not at 0, and a part of that how can I find the average of a signal expressed in this way?

Comment: Shouldn't you sum over $k$ instead over $n$?

Comment: yes , i have corrected it @MattL.

Comment: it's not hard to make the summation start at zero.  just factor out the 1-th term.

Comment: or do the *add-and-subtract-the-same-quantity-trick*.

Comment: yeah i was thinking of make the sum start from 0 and the subtract the value for k=0 , but then the upper limit is infinite so how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

No solutions to homework problems, but here are two hints:

1. what is $e^{j2\pi nk}$ for integer $k$ and $n$?
2. do the values of $x[n]$ depend on $n$?

Comment: i think they depends on k  , but it aint homework , i'm just prep for an exam i have in 2 weeks

Comment: @GiovanniCerciello: If you sum over $k$ then there's no $k$ in the result.

Comment: so it depends on n ? @mat